# Expresiones regulares en operaciones aritméticas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, regex

Hola amigos alguien me podría orientar ¿cómo puedo validar un ecuación algebraica simple? Ejemplo de **casos válidos**:

`a+s, -a+s, a+s-2.1, a+b+f`

Eejemplo de casos **no válidos**:

`sd + v-, --sd*sd, sd++sd`

Bueno básicamente debo de validar que en el inicio no aparezca ningún signo excepto - y al final de la cadena que no aparezca ningún signo y que no duplique los signos inmediatamente después de aparecer

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular

```
[a-z]{1}([+]|[-]|[\/]|[*])[a-z]{1}[,]*
```

Explicación: https://regex101.com/r/faZdoO/2/

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, pero yo recomendaría agregar la explicación al cuerpo de tu respuesta. Saludos